# Selenium (python3) find an element by value and then select the button

Tags: python, selenium

I am trying to find a specific button when there are multiple buttons with the same name.  So I have to find the element with the correct 'id' and then click the button nested within.  I've been able to do this using the logical xpath but they change the path when new items are added to the page.

Right now, I'm just using:
`driver.find_element_by_xpath('/html/body/div[3]/div/div[2]/div[1]/div/div[4]/button').click();`

```
    <input type="hidden" name="data[brand_id]" class="brand-id" value="33" id="brand_id">
    <div class="input number">
        <label for="num-barrels=33">Number of barrels:</label>
        <input name="data[num_barrels]" class="number-of-barrels" min="1" id="num-barrels=33" type="number" value="1">
    </div>
    <button class="add-brand-to-order btn btn-primary btn-block" type="submit">Add to Order</button> 
</div>
```

Comment: Try with browser.find_element_by_xpath('/html/body/div[3]/div/div[2]/div[1]/div/div[4]/button[text()="Add to Order"]').click();

Comment: My xpath example already works.  I just don't think it is reliable since the path can change as new items are added to the page.  I only want to click the button for example "brand-id" "45"

Comment: @JackStack Any static and unique property for either of the nodes among `<label>` and `<input>` within the parent `<div>`?

Comment: Yes, the "num-barrels=33" in label and id="num-barrels=33" are both unique identifiers that I would like to use to make sure I grab the correct item

Answer (score 0):

You can use `driver.find_element_by_id().click()`

Here is the full documentation for this. [Selenium](https://selenium-python.readthedocs.io/locating-elements.html)

Comment: I've done that but by css_selector and I believe found the correct element.  The problem is that part is not clickable.